# Error display after few debugging in flutter, "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

```
[Unhandled exception:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
#0      Session._refreshSessionData.parseContents (package:unified_analytics/src/session.dart:85:43)
#1      Session._refreshSessionData (package:unified_analytics/src/session.dart:89:7)
#2      new Session (package:unified_analytics/src/session.dart:28:5)
#3      new AnalyticsImpl (package:unified_analytics/src/analytics.dart:427:23)
#4      new Analytics (package:unified_analytics/src/analytics.dart:83:12)
#5      getAnalytics (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/unified_analytics.dart:51:10)
#6      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:92:24)
#7      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:107:42)
#8      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:543:23)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:95:20)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:124:32)
#11     analytics (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:96:36)
#12     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:190:13)
#13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:142:13)
#14     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1423:47)
#15     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1315:19)
#16     runZonedGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1776:18)
#17     _Zone._processUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1081:14)
#18     _CustomZone.handleUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1285:5)
#19     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:788:16)
#20     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:651:5)
#21     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:737:7)
#22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:13)
#23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1301:19)
#24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)
#25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1249:23)
#26     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#27     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#28     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#29     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)]
```

[image]

When I initially debugged my project, there were no errors. However, after a few debugging sessions, an error suddenly occurred. Despite restarting Visual Studio and attempting to create a new project, the same error persisted. Additionally, reinstalling Flutter and Dart did not resolve the issue.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: session.dart has problem, please share that code as well

Comment: did u try 1. dart pub cache repair or 2. dart pub cache clean.  As ur image say ??

Comment: where to find session.dart in new project? 

yes, i already did dart pub cache repair and dart pub cache clean, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install flutter master

steps to resolved

- Disable flutter and Dart extension in visual studio code
- Open Git Bash in Directory c:/ and run this

  git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  ./flutter/bin/flutter --version
- then do flutter doctor
- Done[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXxKi.png)

Answer (score -1):

In the session.dart file see line 85. It is mainly due to passing a value that is null or that could be null to an int type one. so see if that value could be null or if you haven't given it a value or it is nullable

Comment: Can't find session.dart file in newly created project.